# Failed to create workflow job because of insufficient permissions in dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I apologize in advance in asking this question. It must be something very silly that I am overlooking. I am a beginner to GCP. When I try to create a job using the GUI and google pubsub to bigquery template, I get the following error:

> [The workflow could not be created. Causes: (717932ea69118a95): Unable to get machine type information for machine type n1-standard-4 in zone us-central1-a because of insufficient permissions. Please refer to https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/access-control#creating_jobs and make sure you have sufficient permissions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cszqj.png)

I went to the IAM and checked that I already am the owner of the project. Can someone please guide me?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess... Do you have Compute API enabled?

Comment: I had not set up authentication. After I downloaded the .json file containnig the secret key, the probelm was resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We faced the similar issue.The root cause we found was the dataflow service account was missing in the IAM.
You should find a service account similar to below:

```
service-xxxxxxxxxxxx@<<project_name>>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

If you dont find this, try disabling the Dataflow API and re enable it.

Comment: try disabling the Dataflow API and re enable it. , this worked for me , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need roles/compute.viewer role for SA

Answer (score -1):

We solved this by making the user `dataflow.admin` in the IAM console.  The [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/access-control#creating_jobs) provided in the error message has more granular permissions you can add if you don't want your data flow developers to be full admin.

Comment: Giving admin permissions is never a good practice. Always follow Principle of least privileges.